# How would I persist the user token state so that my button would remain on the page even if refreshing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, debugging, react-hooks

I'm sort of confused here.  I'm trying to show the Login button if the user's authenticated.  It sort of works.  The Login button appears when the user's authenticated.

However, upon refreshing the page - it disappears again.  I know this is related to an async/sync thing but I'm still kind of lost.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's Navbar.js

```
import { Navbar, Nav, Container, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const NavBar = () => {
    const [authToken, getAuthToken] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        var token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        getAuthToken(token);
    });

    return (
        <>
            <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
                <Container>
                    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
                    { authToken !== null ? <Nav className="me-auto"><Button>Logout</Button></Nav> : null }
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
        </>
    );
}

export default NavBar;
```

This is my Store:

```
import React, {createContext, useReducer} from "react";
import Reducer from '../Reducer/Reducer'

const initialState = {
    token: ''
};

const Store = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, initialState);
    return (
        <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
};

export const Context = createContext(initialState);
export default Store;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refresh the page, state is reset. Nothing in state is persisted between reloads of the page. You're reloading the initial state for your entire application.

If you want to persist your token, you'll have to do so in a storage mechanism (a cookie, local storage, etc.) and then read from that as the page loads. You should expire those items at some point. You may still get a flicker of the button being invisible, but it'll pop-in when the data is read.

Comment: Interesting. I believe I'm sort of experiencing what you've written. I've updated the code in my original post to use `useState()` and `localStorage` - Upon authentication, I don't see the logout button. But if I refresh the page, the logout button appears and stays if I refresh again. How can I make the logout button appear and stay the first time I login without having to refresh? I feel like I'm kind of close